# Why isn't this function triggered upon .click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We need to load a given function on page load. Then, we should repeat that function execution, each time a given button is clicked. How can we do that?

Here's the code:

```
$(function showMember() {

        $.ajax({ //Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

            success: function(html){
                $('#members').append(html);
            },

            type: 'get',
            url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('member'); ?>', //A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
            data: {index:$('#members div>h3').size()},
            cache: false, //if false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.
            dataType: 'html' //The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
        });
    });

$('.addMember').click(showMember);
```

`showMember` doesn't trigger uppon click.

Can anyone please explain with detail, why is that ?

Comment: I believe this was a legit doubt, that required some help to understand, hence the question. Plus, I don't like anonymous downvoters. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an addendum to bipen's answer: the reason your code does not work is because you don't seem to get what `$` is.

Since you have tagged your question with jQuery, I assume that you are using it. When you include the jQuery library in your code it gives you a function called `jQuery`. This function is aliased as `$`. That is, `$` is the same as `jQuery`.

When you call a function in javascript you can pass in arguments:

```
parseInt('1234');
```

At the top of your code you are calling `$`, and passing a function definition as an argument. So

```
$(function showMember()...
```

is the same as

```
jQuery(function showMember()...
```

That is syntactically correct, but limits the scope of the function to the list of arguments you have passed to the `$` function. Once that call is complete the function `showMember` will no longer exist.

This is why you code does not work.

Answer (score 4):

that is because your created function is in limited scope `$(function ..)`....
you can simply do

```
  $(function(){ //document.ready function
    showMember();  //call showmember when document is ready
    $('.addMember').click(showMember); //call same function when clicked
  });

  function showMember() {

    $.ajax({ //Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

        success: function(html){
            $('#members').append(html);
        },

        type: 'get',
        url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('member'); ?>', //A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
        data: {index:$('#members div>h3').size()},
        cache: false, //if false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.
        dataType: 'html' //The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please allow me to ask, why to we need to call the .click function inside $(function()... ? Thanks.

Comment: to make sure.. click event is called after all the elements in document is loaded.... calling click event before the document sometimes gives you error since the handler won't be able to find the elements attached to it

Answer (score 1):

When you pass custom `function` inside **event handler (i.e click, change etc )** then you need to create function as normal, You do not need wrap `function` within `$();`

And also do not forget to wrap code inside `$(document).ready();`

```
function showMember()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        success: function(html)
        {
            $('#members').append(html);
        },
        type: 'get',
        url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('member'); ?>',
        data: {index:$('#members div>h3').size()},
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addMember').click(showMember);
});
```

Comment: i don't think this function will be called on docuemnt.ready though.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are few points:-

- You don't need to call `$(function showMember()` like this.
- You need to call it like `function showMember()` simply.
- Also, you need to call the `click` function inside the DOM ready method.
- Just to make sure that your click event is fired when the DOM is fully loaded, as follows:

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addMember').click(showMember);
});
```

OR

```
$(function () {
    $('.addMember').click(showMember);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ready function when using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.addMember').click({});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.addMember').click(function(){
  showMember();
});

function showMember(){
 $.ajax({ //Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.
            success: function(html){
                $('#members').append(html);
            },
            type: 'get',
            url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('member'); ?>', //A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
            data: {index:$('#members div>h3').size()},
            cache: false, //if false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.
            dataType: 'html' //The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have this lement bind dynamically,
 so I think you need to bind it after all binding is complete :

```
$('.addMember').live('click', function(){
   showMember(); return false;
});
```